# How to apply slimscroll to document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slimscroll

I want to apply slimscroll to the whole webpage. something like on paytm . com ..
I am trying this way, but it isnt working.

```
$(document).slimScroll({
  alwaysVisible: true,
  railVisible: true
});
```

What can be the solution?

Comment: I'm trying the same thing lol, were you able to apply it ?

Comment: No.. Comment if you are able to figure it out

Comment: Done using perfectScroll js. 
https://jsfiddle.net/5ep90ws8/1/
Download the perfectScroll js file and its css from the resources. and use basic css.